# Django session, emite: Object of type '' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, session

Estou criando um aluno porém quando tento salva-lo dentro de uma sessão, me retorna o seguinte erro:

***Object of type 'Student' is not JSON serializable***

***No settings.py:***

```js
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions', <---- já esta no INSTALED_APPS
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap4',
    'registrations',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', <---- já esta no MIDDLEWARE
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

***views.py do app:***

```js
from django.shortcuts import render,  redirect
from .models import Student, StudentForm, StudentDescriptionForm, ParentStudent, ParentStudentForm

# LISTAR TODOS OS ALUNOS


def list_students(request):
    students = Student.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'students.html', {'students': students})

# CRIAR UM NOVO ALUNO


def create_student(request):
    form = StudentForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        student = Student(**form.cleaned_data)
        print(student)
        request.session['student'] = student <--- inicio a sessão
        form.save()
        return redirect('registrations:parent_student')

    return render(request, 'student-form-registration.html', {'form': form})

# CRIAR UM NOVO RESPONSÁVEL / PAI


def parent_student(request):
    form = ParentStudentForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        parent_student = ParentStudent(**form.cleaned_data)
        print(parent_student)
        form.save()
        return redirect('registrations:list_students')

    return render(request, 'parent-student-form-registration.html', {'form': form})


# INSERIR A DESCRIÇÃO NO ALUNO


def student_description(request, id):
    student = Student.objects.get(id=id)
    form = StudentDescriptionForm(request.POST or None, instance=student)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')

    return render(request, 'student-description-form.html', {'form': form , 'student': student})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que você pode alterar para a seguinte forma:

No início do seu script:

```
 from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
```

Na parte que você salva na sessão:

```
 request.session['student'] = model_to_dict(student)
```

Eu particularmente, iria preferir salvar apenas o `id` na sessão, para recuperá-lo posteriormente.

Algo como:

```
 request.session['student_id'] = student.id
```

Depois poderia fazer a consulta através do `student_id`.

Tirei a ideia dessa resposta no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16790455/3096922)

Comment: Wallace Maxters, realmente, eu precisava mandar 1 item do objeto e não ele inteiro, então quando usei "  request.session['student_id'] = student.id " deu certo e dps pra resgatar nas demais telas eu uso " 'student_id' in request.session: " e nas demais funções além do (request) eu chamo (request, id)